# Getting orderID and total amount in Woocommerce? why so difficult?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added this function in my themes functions.php but it just not working.. any idea what i do wrong?

```
function woocommerce_thankyou_fun( $order_id ) 
{
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );  
    // $ttotal = $order->get_order_total();
    //echo trim( str_replace( '#', '', $order->get_order_number() ) );
    //$order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
    //$order = new WC_Order($GLOBALS['post']->ID);
    echo  $order;    
}

add_shortcode('Woocommerce-Thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_fun');
```

Comment: *What* is not working? Is there any error message, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: it return null... now value

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to see all datamember of order object.

```
function woocommerce_thankyou_fun( $order_id ) 
{
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );  

  echo  "<pre>";   
  print_r( $order);
  echo  "</pre>";   

 die();

}

add_shortcode('woocommerce-thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_fun',20,1);
```